# How can I stop my keyboard from ignoring duplicate key presses?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, keyboard

I recently reinstalled Windows 8.1 on my notebook computer. Prior to the reinstall, the keyboard was working fine. After reinstalling, the keyboard omits key strokes when the same key is pressed in rapid succession. It may be similar to the "Filter Keys" functionality (or some combination of Ease of Access tools), but I don't believe this is related to those tools - they're all disabled (including the shortcuts to enable them).

The problem requires a *very* rapid succession of keystrokes. It does not matter which key it is, they all behave this way (both printable and non-printable characters).

I've tried enabling and disabling all Ease of Access tools in both Control Panel and via the registry. I've tried deleting the keyboard from Device Manager and reinstalling. I've searched for alternative keyboard drivers from both Microsoft and HP (Standard PS/2 Keyboard) but cannot find any. Googling for this problem turns up many results of people struggling to disable Filter Keys, but this does not fit my case.

This problem is incredibly frustrating.

**Edit:**
The settings in Control Panel > Keyboard (repeat rate and repeat delay) are unrelated, although I did try changing them to see if they would have any effect... nay.

**Edit:** The notebook is an HP 17-e016DX, and the keyboard is built-in. The only details I know about it are what's in device manager. Standard PS/2 Keyboard, driver version 6.3.9600.17808 (Microsoft), Hardware ID HPQ8001.

**Edit:** Just want to mention that this afflicts all software on the machine, it's not application specific. As an example, if I rapidly type two double-quote characters (""), I'll end up with only one double-quote ("). This happens for all characters, even backspacing.

**Edit:** This doesn't appear to have anything to do with Filter Keys or any other "Ease of Access" features - those are all fully disabled. It's throwing away the second key when I press any key twice rapidly.

**How can this be resolved?**

Comment: Check the settings in control panel > keyboard > speed > Repeat rate and Repeat delay.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill - those are unrelated, but I did already tinker with them to see if they would help... unfortunately not.

Comment: What exact model are teh computer and keyboard?

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, I've added some details about the computer and keyboard.

Comment: You might try editing the value in the Registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard\KeyboardDelay` . Set it to zero for least delay.

Comment: Thanks @DrMoishePippik. It appears that entry is the same as Control Panel > Keyboard > Repeat Delay (under Control Panel). Unfortunately that only controls how long you must hold down a key before windows starts to repeat that keystroke. My issue is different. `For example, I'm typing {{ but the application only gets {`

Comment: Look into *Control Panel > Ease of Access Center > Make the keyboard easier to use > Turn on Filter Keys > Set up Filter Keys > Set up Repeat and Slow Keys > Turn on Repeat Keys and Slow Keys > Set up Repeat Keys and Slow Keys*. You will find there various ways for slowing down the input. Experimentation will help finding the settings that work in your case.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, this does not seem to be related to Filter Keys... all "Ease of Access" features are completely disabled.

Comment: The idea is to enable Slow Keys.